# Autoscroll to the BOTTOM of the page in a set time window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasekit on Fluid.app. In other words, I'm using Javascript.

I would like to scroll to the **bottom** of the page IF the time is between 1900-1910 (i.e. between 7pm and 7:10pm)

So, this question has two components, would be so grateful if someone could help me make the code for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body.scrollTop` (or `window.scrollTop` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop`) to set the scroll position. Since it differs between browsers, you might use [`jQuery.scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method.

To determine the time, you need to use `new Date().getHours()` and `getMinutes()` methods.

You will also have to use `window.setTimeout()` to check from (for example) every 5 seconds if the is right.

Comment: Hey, but i would like to page down (or scroll down) to the **bottom** of the page (not the top).

Comment: Also, could you please spoon feed me the code? i'm totally new to javascript and even newer to jQuery. (If you don't have time, I'll try and figure it out, but it would be super if you could do it)